# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'QDate' pyqt sql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pyqt5

i using a pyqt gui application to extract the histrory from my database using the folowing function

```
def historique_jr_date(self):
        database = QSqlDatabase("QPSQL")
        database.setHostName("localhost")
        database.setDatabaseName("database")
        database.setUserName("postgres")
        database.setPassword("password")
        database.open()
        
        model_hjd = QSqlTableModel(db=database)
        model_hjd.setTable('transactions')
        
        model_hjd.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        
        date = str(self.dateEdit_2.text())
        selected_day = self.dateEdit_2.date()
        last_day = selected_day.addDays(-1)
        last_day_str = last_day.toString(self.dateEdit_2.displayFormat())
        print(last_day_str)
        
        self.tableView_3.setModel(model_hjd)
        self.tableView_3.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        #idx = model_ft.fieldIndex("max(id)")
        model_hjd.setSort(7, Qt.DescendingOrder)
        model_hjd.select()
        filter_ft = "(date_d, time_d) > ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND (date_d, time_d) < ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) " % (selected_day, last_day)
        model_hjd.setFilter(filter_ft)

        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                               password="password",
                               host="localhost",
                               database="database")
        self.cur = self.connection.cursor()

        self.cur.execute( '''SELECT SUM(montant) AS total FROM transactions WHERE (date_d, time_d) > ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND (date_d, time_d) < ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time)''',(selected_day, last_day))
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        for i in result:
            o = i[0]
            oo = str(o)

        self.lineEdit_19.setText(oo)
```

but i get this error

```
self.cur.execute( '''SELECT SUM(montant) AS total FROM transactions WHERE (date_d, time_d) > ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time) AND (date_d, time_d) < ('%s'::date, '16:00:00'::time)''',(selected_day, last_day))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'QDate'
```

and the table view don't show any result at all

is there a way to fix this

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: psycopg2 cannot deal with Qt QDate object (which is reasonable). You need to use a date format suitable for the field you're using, possibly by using [`QDate.toString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#toString-2).

Comment: i try to convert to sting but no result in the QtableView or in the sql statement

Comment: Open the python shell (maybe through iPython, which has completion support), try to run commands from there to see what the various toString options do. And please, study the documentation, this is at least your third question about the same topic. If you're using QDate, you *must* read all its [reference page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `selected_day` and `last_day` is `QDate`.Convert them to strings, eg.:

```
(selected_day.toString(Qt.ISODate), last_day.toString(Qt.ISODate))
```

Read about `QDate.toString()` in [the documentation.](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QDate.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QDate.toString)

Comment: sorry it give me this error `NameError: name 'ISODate' is not defined` ; and whene i remove ISODate it give me this one `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "Wed"
LINE 1: ...tal FROM transactions WHERE (date_d, time_d) > (''Wed Jan 1 ...`

Comment: Of course, `ISODate` is from `Qt`, see the updated answer.

Comment: now it work but the pb is in my database the date format is like this " 10/01/2020 " and the result of selected_day.toString(Qt.ISODate) is  date formate like this 2020-10-01 so it give me no result at all

Comment: Postgres correctly interprets the ISO date as input, regardless of local settings.